# How do I inhibit the initial line segment of an AngleArc()?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I want to use the `AngleArc()` function in paths, but sometimes I'd like to not have the "draws the line segment from the current position to the beginning of the arc" behavior written on MSDN.

Right now, I'm trying this by creating a new path each time I want to inhibit this behavior:

```
        BeginPath(dc);
        MoveToEx(dc, 100, 100, NULL);
        AngleArc(dc, 100, 100, 50, 30, 300);
        LineTo(dc, 100, 100);
        EndPath(dc);
        StrokePath(dc);

        BeginPath(dc);
        AngleArc(dc, 210, 100, 50, 30, 300);
        CloseFigure(dc);
        EndPath(dc);
        StrokePath(dc);
```

the thought here being that each new path starts with no current point, and thus `AngleArc()` would simply start drawing the arc with no starting line segment, as it does in other vector graphics toolkits. However, this doesn't work:

[image: what I don't want]

The effect I'm trying to get is this, drawn with cairo on a Linux GTK+ program:

[image: what I want]

So is there a way to do what I want? I don't see a function that starts a new subpath in GDI, and I also don't see a way to unset the current point; is there always a current point in GDI? Or am I going to have to calculate the starting point myself, or convert the `AngleArc()` parameters to `Arc()`/`ArcTo()`/`Pie()` parameters?

Thanks.

```
// 8 september 2015
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
#define CINTERFACE
#define COBJMACROS
// see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9916#issuecomment-74812211
#define INITGUID
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
// get Windows version right; right now Windows Vista
#define WINVER 0x0600               /* according to Microsoft's winnls.h */
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600     /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0600       /* according to Microsoft's pdh.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <math.h>

HPEN pen;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC dc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HPEN prevpen;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        prevpen = SelectObject(dc, pen);
        SetDCPenColor(dc, RGB(0, 0, 0));

        BeginPath(dc);
        MoveToEx(dc, 100, 100, NULL);
        AngleArc(dc, 100, 100, 50, 30, 300);
        LineTo(dc, 100, 100);
        EndPath(dc);
        StrokePath(dc);

        BeginPath(dc);
        AngleArc(dc, 210, 100, 50, 30, 300);
        CloseFigure(dc);
        EndPath(dc);
        StrokePath(dc);

        SelectObject(dc, prevpen);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    pen = GetStockObject(DC_PEN);

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"mainwin",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400, 400,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use `MoveToEx` to set the new current point.

Comment: I am just guessing, but by moving the lines which move the current position to outside of the `BeginPath` and `EndPath` enclosure?

Comment: @JonathanPotter yeah, that's what I had feared; I would just need to figure out how Windows determines where the starting point is (to avoid the risk of having a stray line segment due to rounding differences between Windows's calculations and mine own)

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that `MoveToEx` doesn't draw a line, but Jonathan's comment is better: You did not reposition the current point before starting the second figure.

Comment: `AngleArc` draws a line segment and an arc. `Arc` just draws an arc. Can't you use that? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Or `ArcTo`?

Comment: @WeatherVane That still has the problem of where do I place the start and end points? That being said, I'll do the mathematically pure calculation and see what happens.

Comment: `ArcTo` does at least become the current position....

Comment: Okay, so I calculated where the start coordinate *would* be, but I'm not getting a perfectly straight vertical line like I get in the cairo reference image, so I'm guessing there is rounding error with pure `double` calculations...

Comment: Suggest then using `Arc` and the same x-coord for joining.

Comment: Okay, with `Arc` and `floor(x+0.5)` style rounding I get a perfectly straight line; I can use that for now, though I'm not sure how accurate that is to `AngleArc()`'s behavior. That being said, thanks in the meantime!